# Wrong parameters passed to function C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a self-learning snake game and encountered an issue that I'm trying to resolve for the last several hours. Here is the code where I move the snake head:

```
        public void moveTo()
        {
            int foodX = food.PosX / food.Width;
            int foodY = food.PosY / food.Height;        
            Direction directionOfMaxForCurrentState= new Direction();
            int currentX = head.PosX / head.Width;
            int currentY = head.PosY / head.Height;          
            do
            {
                int tmpX = currentX;
                int tmpY = currentY;
                 previousX = tmpX;
                 previousY = tmpY;
                directionOfMaxForCurrentState = HighestQactionForState(currentX, currentY, previousX, previousY);
                if (directionOfMaxForCurrentState == Direction.Up) {  head.PosY -= head.Height; }
                if (directionOfMaxForCurrentState == Direction.Down) {  head.PosY += head.Height; }
                if (directionOfMaxForCurrentState == Direction.Left) {  head.PosX -= head.Width; }
                if (directionOfMaxForCurrentState == Direction.Right) {head.PosX += head.Width; }
                currentX = head.PosX / head.Width;
                currentY = head.PosY / head.Height; 
                if (currentX == foodX && currentY == foodY) { snake.Clear(); head = new Cell(1, 1); snake.Add(head); }
            } while (head.PosX == food.PosX && head.PosY == food.PosY);
        }
```

And here is HighestQactionForState function:

```
public Direction HighestQactionForState(int x, int y, int px, int py)
        {
            var Qaround = new List<decimal>();
            var actionsWithMax = new List<Direction>();
            Direction toExclude = new Direction();
            toExclude = directionToExclude(x, y, px, py);
            foreach (Direction action in PosibleActionsForState(x, y).Where(a => a != toExclude).ToList())
            {
                if (action == Direction.Up && (double)Math.Abs(Q[Tuple.Create(x, y - 1, action)] - MaxQaroundState(x, y)) < 0.000000000000000000000001) actionsWithMax.Add(action);
                if (action == Direction.Down && (double)Math.Abs(Q[Tuple.Create(x, y + 1, action)] - MaxQaroundState(x, y)) < 0.000000000000000000000001) actionsWithMax.Add(action);
                if (action == Direction.Left && (double)Math.Abs(Q[Tuple.Create(x - 1, y, action)] - MaxQaroundState(x, y)) < 0.000000000000000000000001) actionsWithMax.Add(action);
                if (action == Direction.Right && (double)Math.Abs(Q[Tuple.Create(x + 1, y, action)] - MaxQaroundState(x, y)) < 0.000000000000000000000001) actionsWithMax.Add(action);
            }
            return actionsWithMax.ElementAt(rnd.Next(actionsWithMax.Count));
        }
```

So now when I put the breakpoint in the moveTo function I see that HighestQactionForState gets the right parameters, but in the HighestQactionForState function the parameters are not correct - px always has the same value as int x, and py is the same as y which causing the program to behave wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because your previous and current coordinates are the same. All you're doing is using temp variables as an intermediary, but you aren't changing either value.

Comment: It's because they're the same when you call the method: currentX==tmpX==previousX

Comment: The behavior is expected because  LOOK at values you set before calling method

Comment: Well see what `HighestQactionForState` is retuning. Test that first by passing it hard coded values and make sure it is returning the expected result. Then take everything from inside the loop and put that into a method and test that method by passing it hard-code values. Once they both work then remove the hardcoded values and connect the 2 methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistaken you should do this instead

```
directionOfMaxForCurrentState = HighestQactionForState(currentX, currentY, previousX, previousY);
previousX = currentX;
previousY = currentY;
```

You set previous values after you call method so by the meaning of variables they have values set in previous iteration.

Also there is no need for declaring extra temp variables. Your parameters are passed by value not by reference.